# How to return JSON response from a query with eloquent?

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

**I am working on this query:** (I wish I could pass this same query using eloquent and return a JSON as response.)

```
public function getChart(Request $request)
    {      
        $_orders = DB::table('users')
            ->join('orders','orders.user_id','=','users.id')
            ->join('model_has_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.model_id')                        
            ->select('users.id','users.name', DB::raw('COUNT(orders.id) as orders_by_user'), 'model_has_roles.role_id as rol')                   
            ->where('model_has_roles.role_id', '2');
        $_orders->groupBy('orders.user_id', 'users.id',  'users.name',  'model_has_roles.role_id');
        $orders=$_orders->get();

        return ['orders' => $orders];

    }
```

This query is already resolved and returns me as a result: **the name of the operator who was assigned a work order and the number of work orders in finished state that that operator has.**
for this, relate the users table and the orders table.

```
{
"orders": [
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"orders_by_user": 2,
"rol": 2
},
{
"id": 6,
"name": "Jose",
"orders_by_user": 1,
"rol": 2
},
{
"id": 7,
"name": "Miguel",
"orders_by_user": 1,
"rol": 2
}
]
}
```

If you look at my query response, **my array is called orders inside orders I get what I need:**

```
"orders": [
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"orders_by_user": 2,
"rol": 2
},
```

**As I mentioned earlier, I wish I could pass this same query using eloquent and return a JSON in response.**

**How can I customize this JSON response?**
It would be something like this: **separate name in one array and orders_by_user in another array**

**example of what I want to achieve**

```
"users": [
{

"name": "Luis"
}
]
"orders": [
{

"orders_by_user": 2

}
]
```

**I need your help**

Answer (score 2):

you can return json response like this

```
return response()->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA'])
```

read documentation here

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#json-responses

**Note**
explaining relations to @Rodrigo Ruiz

in user model has your relation like this

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function Orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Order::class);
    }
}
```

Order Model

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
    }
}

$user = User::first();
```

get all orders of user

```
$orders = $user->orders()->get();
```

get first order

```
$order = $user->orders()->first();
```

if you call relation each time it will execute a query on each call.

Optimize call of relations it will load all relations just in 1 query.

```
$user = User::with('orders')->get();

$order = $user->orders->first();
```

Comment: I understand but how did you pass that same query with eloquent !? could guide me with that so first I get username and number of orders per user

Comment: you need to create Relations between models tell me each user can have how many roles?

Comment: a user can have the role of supervisory operator or administrator. you can ignore this line -> join ('model_has_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.model_id') and just bringing username and orders per user would only relate the orders and users table

Comment: Please check my answer i have updated with Model relations.

Comment: muy buena tu aclaración entoces me dices que con la consulta que me das como respuesta obtengo este resultado'''{
  "users": ["Luis", "Jose" ....]
  "orders": [2, 3, 5 ....]
}''' dónde por ejemplo para el operario Luis tiene 2 ordenes terminadas por favor confirma lo que estoy suponiendo.

Answer (score 1):

- List item

[@umefarooq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/629673/umefarooq) is right,  I always follow his steps and sometimes if I don't want it to return all the values of that particular model, I return the result through [Laravel API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources). This gives you the flexibility to determine which fields you will like to return from the eloquent query.

In your controller, rather than use it like

```
return response()->json($order);
```

I use it like this

```
 return OrderResource::collection($orders);
```

You can customize this query to any style you want as long as you know how to 
pass all required parameters into the collection.
So if you want to fetch just the basic information about a user and order:

```
class OrderResource extends JsonResource
return [
           'user'=>[
                'id' => $this->id,
                'name' => $this->name,
                  ],
            'orders'=>[
                'order_id' => $this->order->order_id,
                'order_rol' =>  $this->rol
            ]
        ];
```

Comment: @Doble Príncipe claro es algo como lo que me comentas lo que estoy buscando tengo que ver indagar más con el enlace que me compartiste https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources

Comment: This is just a sample. you can read more on it and enjoy its rich API resource formatting possibilities.